# Is there an elegant way to get only one dimension from a two dimensional array in JavaScript or angularjs?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, multidimensional-array

Is there a way to get just one dimension of the array without looping through the whole array to extract them?

To prove that I have actually attempted to solve my own issue before asking a question on this site, I have attempted to use filters and loops to get the data that I need.  I settled on the for each option I have entered below.

Here is my sample data:

```
dataArray = 
 [ 
 {id: 'ABCDEF', name: 'ABC DEF'},
 {id:'WINDY', name: 'Windy' },
 {id: 'RSTETC', name: 'RST ETC'},
 {id: 'MCHSDXCVDEULH', name: 'MCHS DXCVD EULH'}
 ]
```

Here is what I have done to get all of the name values into a new array:

```
if (dataArray.length) {
 var nameList =[];
 angular.forEach(dataArray, function(dep, idx) {
   nameList.push(dep.name);
 });
}
```

Comment: `dataArray.map(e => e.name);`?.. Are names unique? if so, you may use a `Set`: `Array.from(new Set(dataArray.map(e => e.name)));`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.map()`. As from [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

> The `map()` method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

```js
let data = [ 
 {id: 'ABCDEF', name: 'ABC DEF'}, {id:'WINDY', name: 'Windy' },
 {id: 'RSTETC', name: 'RST ETC'}, {id: 'MCHSDXCVDEULH', name: 'MCHS DXCVD EULH'}
];

let result = data.map(({ name }) => name);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Array#map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). It creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

```js
dataArray = [ 
 {id: 'ABCDEF', name: 'ABC DEF'},
 {id:'WINDY', name: 'Windy' },
 {id: 'RSTETC', name: 'RST ETC'},
 {id: 'MCHSDXCVDEULH', name: 'MCHS DXCVD EULH'}
];

console.log(
  dataArray.map(data => data.name)
)
```

Note though, that this will still internally loop through the array, there is no way around that.

Answer (score 1):

use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/map) method.
In your case it should be something like this.

`dataArray = dataArray.map(data => data.name);`

Answer (score 0):

Map would have been the perfect answer to this question, except in my particular situation, we had to support IE versions, so this was not a viable option.  I had to keep the code the way I had entered it, with the looping.  :(